# How to solve this combinatorial question (Phone number consists of 7 digits)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Question I tried to solve, the question is:

A phone number has 7 digits.

A) How many phone numbers have exactly 2 or exactly 3 instances of zero?

B) How many phone numbers have exactly 3 instances of zero when not two of them are linked to each other?

C) Want to divide phone numbers between 3 different phone companies. In some ways this can be done if there is no restriction
On the number of numbers in each company

I tried using (n + k-1)Ck

For example in a) 8C2+9C3=112

and for

b) I found several times they did appear together and I did a subtraction
(7+3-1)C3 -5 =79

Please help me understand the way to solve such questions

Answer (score 1):

I'll just get you started.

To count the number of phone numbers with exactly $n$ $0$s, we first pick $n$ spots to be $0$s in ${7}\choose{n}$ ways and then fill the rest out with non-zeros in $(7-n)^{9}$ ways, for a total of $(7-n)^{9} {{7}\choose{n}}$ ways.

For B you will reason similarly, but replace ${7}\choose{n}$ with the total number of ways to pick $n$ zeros such that no two are adjacent.

For C, you know that there are $7^{10}$ possible phone numbers.  How many ways can you partition $7^{10}$ objects into three parts?  Such numbers are known as Stirling numbers of the second kind.